# How do you get a union of constructor args of a class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How do you get a union of constructor args in a class?

Assume we have

```js
class Person {
   constructor(name: string, age: number){}
}
```

How would you get the type `'name' | 'age'` ?

I have tried using

```js
type ConstructorParametersOfPerson = ConstructorParameters<typeof Person>;
```

but this returns a tuple of the object `[name: string, age: number]` and e.g, using `ConstructorParametersOfPerson[0]` returns `string` and somehow throws the parameter key away.

Comment: This is not possible.  Parameter names are intentionally not observable in the type system.  See the answers to the linked questions for more information, and the declined feature request at [ms/TS#31627](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31627).

Comment: So is it essentially IntelliSense that keeps track of the variable names?

Comment: More or less. The information is in the type's "quick info" (which is shown in IntelliSense) but is not available as a string literal.  Type predicates like `(x: X) => x is Y` allow you to refer to parameter names, but they are just dummy names... there's no difference between that type and `(z: X) => z is Y`, so the names `x` and `z` are not really observable.

Comment: That's quite useful to know. so my tuple was actually `[string, number]` but Intellij was just being nice